# ParsePosition equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, java

what is C# equivalent of this java code:

```
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
```

ParsePosition is used for keeping track of current position during parsing in java.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What you want to parse?

Comment: Current Date and Time which I have it as milliseconds

Comment: So why do you need the parse position? Please give more context to your question - it's very hard to help you with so little information. There isn't an equivalent, basically. The parse operations (e.g. `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.ParseExact`, `DateTime.TryParse`, `DateTime.TryParseExact` and likewise for other types) don't offer any such facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *exact* equivalent. However, if you were to use a `FileStream`:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open))
{

}
```

you can use the `Position` property of the `FileStream` to know where you are. So you might read a block of bytes say:

```
fs.Read(bytes, fs.Position, 1024);
```

Where `bytes` is defined like this `byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]`.

**UPDATE:** okay so I answered before there was a comment where you stated that you need to parse a date and time that is in milliseconds. As stated by others, it's not necessary to parse that on your own, you can do it like this:

```
DateTime output = new DateTime(long.Parse(input) * 10000);
```

So here I've used the constructor that takes ticks and so I've multiplied the milliseconds by `10000`. Another possible approach would be:

```
DateTime output = new DateTime(
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(long.Parse(input)).Ticks);
```